# jquery how check an element has hover or not

Tags: jquery, hover

I want to check status of hover of an element, however on this line I receive an error:

```
if ($(this).nextAll('ul:first').is(':hover'))
```

This is the error :

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

What is the solution?

```js
  $(".sf-with-ul").hover(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
    "display": "block"
  });
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeInUpSmall");
}, function() {
  if ($(this).nextAll('ul:first').is(':hover')) {
    console.log('1');
  } else {
    console.log('2');
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeInUpSmall");
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-ps2id-api="true" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Services</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu animated fast fadeInUpSmall" style="display: block;">
  <li id="menu-item-1281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1281"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/active-your-cards/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Activate Your Cards</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1271"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/card-balance/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Check Cards Balance</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Read the question carefully again & see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:hover` gets ignored on margin. Try setting the margin to 0.

```
.sf-with-ul + ul { margin: 0; }
```

**Note:** `padding` will work as expected

```js
$(".sf-with-ul").hover(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
    "display": "block"
  });
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeInUpSmall");
}, function() {
  if ($(this).nextAll('ul:first').is(':hover')) {
    console.log('1');
  } else {
    console.log('2');
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').removeClass("fadeInUpSmall");
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').addClass("fadeOutDownSmall");
  }
});
```

```css
.sf-with-ul + ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-ps2id-api="true" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Services</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu animated fast fadeInUpSmall">
  <li id="menu-item-1281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1281"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/active-your-cards/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Activate Your Cards</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1271"><a href="https://virtualvisacards.com/card-balance/" data-ps2id-api="true"><span>Check Cards Balance</span></a></li>
</ul>
```